# Does the imperial religion have a sacred text?

Tags: warhammer-40k

Almost every religion has a sacred text that is used to store their most sacred beliefs, eg- the Bible, Torah, Qur’an, etc. So far I have not been able to find references to any religious texts that the imperial religion of Warhammer has, having looked on the lexicanum, which I find hard to believe that the millions of priests in the Eclecticasies (imperial church) just pass down everything by word of mouth.

Is there a religious text that the imperial religion regularly use?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, the Lectitio Divinatus. It was written by the Primarch of the Word Bearers, Lorgar Aurelian, before he fell to chaos. The Emperor then forbid it but it was already out there and people began to worship the Emperor as a god.

That is also one of the reasons that it is not very widely known that Lorgar is a daemon prince of chaos undivided, as his book is the basis of the Imperial Faith.

> This faith unified the Imperial people against the myriad threats and horrors of the galaxy in their common belief that "faith in the Emperor protects" until the cult of the Lectitio Divinitatus became the official state religion of the Imperium in the 32nd Millennium in the form of the Temple of the Saviour Emperor.
>
> From the Fandom [article on the Lectitio Divinatus](https://warhammer40k.fandom.com/wiki/Lectitio_Divinitatus)

There are also other books, that can be used:

> Book of Saint Lucius
>
> Few orators in the history of the Imperium have equalled the fiery rhetoric of Saint Lucius of Agatha. The sermons of the famed Confessor have been published and republished countless times on thousands of the worlds across the galaxy. The righteousness of the revered saint's words echo through the long centuries and continue to inspire the faithful to greater acts of devotion.
>
> From the Rogue Trader rulebook *Faith and Coin*, page 97

> Thorian Missal
>
> Also known as the "Book of Hours", the *Thorian Missal* is the illuminated book containing prayers, liturgies, sermons and a calendar of Imperial feast days. This collection of writings is attributed by some to Sebastian Thor, an ancient holy man who came into his ascendency during a time of great conflict in ages past.
>
> Above mentioned rulebook, page 101

Comment: The 40k Fandom wiki is pretty unreliable. It has no inline citations and you can't tell what's plagiarism or what's fanfic. If you must use a wiki, use https://wh40k.lexicanum.com

Comment: @OrangeDog I prefer lexicanum as it is more reliable, as you said. However, saying fandom is unreliable is IMO exaggerated.

Comment: some passages are entirely made up or are dodgy extrapolations. But you have no way to tell which ones unless you already have encyclopaedic knowledge of all the relevant books.